# Would many extremely fine (solid) granules exhibit similar properties as a fluid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, solid-state-physics

A while ago this random thought crossed my mind: I am not even sure if the question is valid or makes sense, but I can sort of imagine a powder (consisting of of granules with a diameter way less than a nanometer across) behaving like a fluid (at least they would have a similar "macroscopic" behaviour). Of course I do not expect this powder to have similar chemical properties, but maybe that's the case.
Is there any information on "simulating fluids with many tiny solid objects"?

Comment: There is *a lot* about granular materials and fluids (their behaviour can range from very fluid-like to utterly different), and in computational fluid dynamics people use Lagrangian fluid solvers where the fluid is approximated by moving points.

Comment: Some powders will flow, but being a solid can resist shear stresses and will not assume the same angle of repose as a liquid. But it is a good question.

Comment: The Wikipedia page for [the properties of water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_water) states that a molecule of $H_2O$ is around 0.3nm across. What will your "powder" be made of to have granules way less than a nanometre across?

Comment: @Dan Pollard I know it may not be very realistic, but I essentially that is what I wanted to say: granules on near-atomary scale.